# Select Values from checked DataGridView Items

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

I have my code as follows:

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chk = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
actGrid.Columns.Add(chk);
chk.HeaderText = "Select";
chk.Name = "select";
chk.ReadOnly = false;

DataGridViewTextBoxColumn mc_no = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
actGrid.Columns.Add(mc_no);
mc_no.HeaderText = "M/C Number";
mc_no.Name = "mc_no";
mc_no.Width = 200;
mc_no.ReadOnly = true;

DataGridViewTextBoxColumn act_name = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
actGrid.Columns.Add(act_name);
act_name.HeaderText = "Name";
act_name.Name = "member";
act_name.Width = 262;
act_name.ReadOnly = true;

while (DR.Read())
{
    actGrid.Rows.Add(true, DR.GetInt32(0).ToString(), DR.GetString(2) + " " + DR.GetString(1));
}
```

Which produces the following output:

[image: DataGrid]

And now I want to perform some actions based on which accounts were selected (by toggling the trailing checkboxes), especially M/C Number.

Answer (score 1):

```
// iterate over DataGridView rows
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in actGrid.Rows)
{
    // check, if row is selected by checkbox
    if (Equals(row.Cells["select"].Value, true))
    {
        // get values for selected row
        var mc_no_Value = (string)row.Cells["mc_no"].Value;
        var member_Value = (string)row.Cells["member"].Value;

        // do smth with values here
    }
}
```